# How to append to listview using javascript in jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, listview, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile and am trying to display a listview.  When I include

```
            <ul data-role="listview" id = "results">
                <li><a href="index.html">Acura</a></li>
            </ul>
```

it behaves like expected.

However, when I try to append elements to the listview using javascript (that comes from json), it displays as a bulleted list...not the stylized listview the first code snippet generates.

```
            var url='http://someurl.com/categories';

            $.getJSON(url,function(json){
                $.each(json,function(i,item){

                    $("#results").append('<li>'+item.category+'</li>');

                });

            });
```

When I inspect the element, I am seeing a lot of html code missing when I append an item using jquery.  What's happening and how do I fix this?

Comment: try calling refresh() on the listview

Comment: That does a little bit but it doesn't add the shading when the item is tapped and the arrow still doesn't appear.

Comment: you may need to put `item.category` inside of an anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

To append the list dynamically, append the list and refresh the list by calling `.listview('refresh')`

Try

```
var url='http://someurl.com/categories';
   $.getJSON(url,function(json){
     $.each(json,function(i,item){
          $("#results").append('<li><a href="#">'+item.category+'</a></li>').listview('refresh');
     });
 });
```